# extending custom(not core based) classes

Tags: magento-1.7, architecture

In my project I have a "lib" directory with different custom libs/classes from php community. But unfortunately I need to extend several classes from "lib" directory.
How can I do that in magento way? I mean, helper doesn't fit for this role because I need to path constructor arguments etc. 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy file to local namespace. For example `lib/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php` copyed to `app/code/local/Varien/Image/Adapter/Gd2.php`

Comment: Sounds like a good solution